# How to fix "SemgrepError Error while running rules: 0 bytes read on a total of 2 expected bytes" error for SemGrep analyzer?

Tags: gitlab, semgrep

I am trying to integrate Gitlab [SAST](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/) into my pipeline and facing the following error for `SemGrep` analyzer during generation of the report.

The error:

```
[DEBU] [Semgrep] [2022-10-11T10:02:55Z] [/go/src/buildapp/analyze.go:137] METRICS: Using configs from the Registry (like --config=p/ci) reports pseudonymous rule metrics to semgrep.dev.
To disable Registry rule metrics, use "--metrics=off".
Using configs only from local files (like --config=xyz.yml) does not enable metrics.
More information: https://semgrep.dev/docs/metrics
Scanning across multiple languages:
    java | 86 rules × 37 files
      js | 13 rules ×  1 file 
[INFO] [Semgrep] [2022-10-11T10:02:55Z] [/go/pkg/mod/gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/command@v1.9.1/run.go:179] Creating report
[DEBU] [Semgrep] [2022-10-11T10:02:55Z] [/go/src/buildapp/convert.go:25] Converting report with the root path: /path/to/my/repo
[FATA] [Semgrep] [2022-10-11T10:02:55Z] [/go/src/buildapp/main.go:27] tool notification error: SemgrepError Error while running rules: 0 bytes read on a total of 2 expected bytes
```

Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change `Gitlab` runner to bigger one (cpu, ram) helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `pcre` for running Semgrep on MacOS Ventura 13.5 with default python 3.9.6

`brew install pcre`

`/Users/<user>/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/semgrep/bin/semgrep-core` => gives exception about missing `lang` parameter

`semgrep scan --debug --config p/javascript` => **works**

`njsscan -o json check src` => **works**

See also https://github.com/returntocorp/semgrep/issues/5876#issuecomment-1659576520